# How to test plugin update through WordPress plugin updater without tagging new release in the repo

Tags: plugin-development, updates

I have been searching for hours trying to find a way to test the update process for my plugin before tagging a new release in the repo. I have a function that is called using `add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'my_plugin_upgrade_function', 10, 2);` and I can't figure out how to test this prior to release.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of the plugin to the lower version than version on WordPress plugin repository.

if current version on WordPress plugin repo is `Version: 2.2.5` then change your version to `Version: 2.2.4` and refresh the plugins page.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand this. Wouldn't this just update to the latest in the repo again when I hit update, which would overwrite my new files where I changed to an older version number for testing? I need to update to my new plugin using the plugin update process in the dashboard.

Comment: host your plugin on bitbucket as private repo or on github and use this plugin https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Comment: i also use zend studion 13 IDE which allows me to pull and push code changes to github and bitbucket, then change the version. and it will show you update and will update through github.

Comment: Thank you! I had a look at that plugin and wondered, having a good read, it seems like it will do the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the update process of your plugin, before you put the current version to the repository, I wrote a plugin for that: https://nikel.co/how-tos/worpress-plugin-dev-test-your-plugin-upgrade-process/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @nikelone I'll have a look. Sounds very helpful.